# How to pass array from method to property using PHP

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, oop

Actually I want to change the color of current topic... Here is my CSS code:

```
.active{
    color: red;
    border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

Also here is my PHP class:

```
class Languages
{
    public $active;
    public $data = '<div class="menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li $active["en"]>English</li>
                            <li $active["fr"]>French</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>';

    function English()
    {
        // other codes
        $this->active["en"] = 'active';
        return $active;
    }

    function French()
    {
        // other codes
        $this->active["fr"] = 'active';
        return $active;
    }

}
```

But the above code does not work, why?! And how can I fix it?

Comment: `$active["en"]` is literally a string. Use placeholders and then replace them with the corresponding values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. Firstly, using single quotes (`'`) instructs PHP to NOT interpolate values. Secondly, I suspect that your `data` value will never actually update as the values in `$active` change. Also, you should be using class="active" not simply adding the word 'active' into your `li` element. A more effective solution may be something like the following

```
class Languages
{
    public $active;

    function English()
    {
        // other codes
        $this->active["en"] = 'active';
        return $active;
    }

    function French()
    {
        // other codes
        $this->active["fr"] = 'active';
        return $active;
    }

    function data()
    {
        return = '<div class="menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="' . $this->active["en"] . '">English</li>
                            <li class="' . $this->active["fr"] . '">French</li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>';
    }

}
```

Then you can access the generated html by calling the `$object->data()` method and your generated HTML will always reflect the current values in `$active`. Alternatively you could still store `$data` as a member variable and simply have a function that regenerates it with new values such as `function updateData()`.

Comment: You forgot to change out `$active["en"]` with the class properties :)

Comment: Thanks for the catch, haha! I have improved my answer.

Comment: @Sajad what is wrong with what he's doing? Be grateful that he is helping others fix their solutions which will in turn help you.

Comment: @Sajad he has no obligation to help you. He does so out of good will, maybe he doesn't have time to post a full answer, or maybe he does but doesn't want to, it's up to **him**.

Comment: How can I implement your solution using `__construct()` instead of a new method (in this case named `data()`) ?

Answer (score 2):

What you were doing is incorrect. Your code wasn't adding the variable values in to the string, it was treating the code as text.

```
public $data = '<div class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li ' . $this->$active["en"] .'>English</li>
                        <li ' . $this->$active["fr"] .'>French</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>';
```

**Edit 1**

You are also missing the ID or class property.

**Edit 2**

As said in the comment to this answer, you'd get errors as the variable hasn't been initialized, add the text to `$data` after you set the active variable in the `__construct` method.

**Edit 3**

Try this,

```
    <?php
    class Languages
    {
        public $active = [];
        public $data;

        function __construct() {
            /** This will run first before anything else. **/

            $this->active["someKey"] = "someValue";
            $this->data = '<div class="menu">
                            <ul>
                                <li class=' . $this->$active["en"] . '>English</li>
                                <li class=' . $this->$active["fr"] . '>French</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>';
        }

        function English()
        {
            // other codes
            $this->active["en"] = 'active';
            return $active;
        }

        function French()
        {
            // other codes
            $this->active["fr"] = 'active';
            return $active;
        }

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Point 1 remains. You use local variables and not class properties. Which then also wouldn't be defined.

Comment: @Rizier123 I just saw what you mean't. Thanks for the help. Updated.

Comment: In your code, when I call `$obj->English()`, then my HTML code will be updated?